# You have 10 glasses and a box with 12 compartments. 7 glasses are white, 1 is purple, 1 green and 1 blue. How many different ways of arranging them?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There is a box with 12 compartments. You want to store 10 glasses in
>   it, all with the same size and shape: 7 white ones, 1 green, 1 blue
>   and 1 purple.
>
> In each compartment you can store only 1 glass. How many different
>   ways can the 10 glasses be stored in that box?
>
> [image]

First I tried to get all sets of 10 out of those 12 compartments:

$$^{12}C_{10} = 66$$

Then for each set I tried to calculate all possibilities:

$$10!$$

So the answer I get is $$^{12}C_{10}\cdot 10! = 239500800$$

But the solution is C). What did I do wrong?

In your answer please tell me exactly **what is wrong with my answer**, first and foremost, and don't just tell me how to solve the problem.

Comment: The white glasses are presumably indistinguishable.  If you had ten glasses, one of which white, one purple, one green, one blue, one off-white, one pearly-white, one cloudywhite etc... then your answer would be correct.  You have overcounted.  Divide by $7!$ to compensate.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $^{5}A_{3}$; can you please explain what this means.

Comment: @MontyHall Sorry about that, I forgot to translate. It's the same as $^5P_3$

Comment: I will point out that there are many different ways to arrive at the same answer, several of which just depending on in what order you take the steps to determine which spots each type of glass are in.  $\binom{12}{7}\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3$ could be explained as first choosing the spots taken by the white glasses, then choosing the location of the green, then purple, then blue.  Similarly, $12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot \binom{9}{7}$ could be explained as first picking the location of the blue, then purple, then green, then picking the spots used by the whites from those remaining

Comment: In the end, perhaps the easiest way to explain the answer is via [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) being $\binom{12}{7,1,1,1,2}=\frac{12!}{7!1!1!1!2!}$.  Of course, all of these answers I refer to are equal.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong is that you differentiated between the 7 white glasses: since they are exactly alike, you don't get a different possibility when you switch 2 white glasses, but your formula does see that as a different packing.

Comment: Alright I fixed it: $^{12}C_{10}\cdot(^{10}C_7\cdot3\cdot2)$. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRead You're welcome! :)